# Wait until the values on a JFrame are introduced

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I have a program that firstly displays a log in screen and I need a way to make my code wait until the user properly logs in in order to send the generated User object to  the screen where the user does what he needs.

```
public class ProgramaCliente {
public static void main (String[] args) {
    VentanaLoggeo vLog = new VentanaLoggeo(); // a log in screen
    vLog.setVisible(true);

    MonedaDAO mDAO = new MonedaDAO(); // a data access object for cryptocurrencies
    InversionDAO iDAO = new InversionDAO(); // a data access object for the crytocurrencies that the user bought
    Usuario user = vLog.getUsuario(); // the user that the log in screen should return

    VentanaCliente vCliente = new VentanaCliente(user,mDAO,iDAO); // -Main screen-  a screen that lets the user manipulate it's cryptocurrencies
    vCliente.setVisible(true);
}
```

Is there a way to do so without instancing the Main screen on the log screen?

Comment: Normally you have to separate your code into sections (typically methods and classes) and only call a particular section when it's needed.  For example, the login screen could call a method to set-up the rest of the app when a user successfully logs in.  As you have it now, the rest of the app is always called by main, and there's no way to change that (make it wait).

Comment: While typically implemented with methods, the common model here is called MVC, with the part that executes code when needed are the C (Controller).  Please read up: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller

Comment: You typically display a modal JDialog to log in to an application.